# control GPIO port through Raspberry PI from Laptop

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I need to run my python code on a high-power laptop and not on the PI itself. How could I access the PI's GPIO ports "directly" from my laptop (Linux)?

I could create an API myself (https://docs.dataplicity.com/docs/control-gpios-using-rest-api) but this is not what I'm looking for.

Best would be to connect my PI via USB to my laptop and then being able to recognise its GPIO's as the laptops own GPIO's and control those directly using pi-gpio library.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a serial connection between devices.

"...via USB to my laptop..." Have you tried using 'USB-to-UART'? USB to laptop and of course UART to Raspberry Pi. Furthermore, it may be controlled remotely using Pigpio.

Maybe this can help a little https://youtu.be/owKEZTPDURs

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I just found "remote GPIO" :)

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html